# OroCRM 4.1.6 VM image from bitnami - Error 404 on /api/rest/latest/navigationitems/pinbar load on every page when behind proxy

Tags: orocrm

I have OroCRM 4.1.6 Bitnami VM running behind an nginx proxy.
Every time a page is loaded I get 404 error on /api/rest/latest/navigationitems/pinbar.
Same thing happens when loading /api/entitystructures when in 'System -> Workflows -> Create workflow'.
OroCRM log info on this:

```
[2020-08-31 12:23:15] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "" at /opt/bitnami/apps/orocrm/htdocs/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/ApiBundle/Security/Http/Firewall/FeatureAccessListener.php line 34 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0):  at /opt/bitnami/apps/orocrm/htdocs/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/ApiBundle/Security/Http/Firewall/FeatureAccessListener.php:34)"} []
```

I've looked through the suggested solutions in https://forum.oroinc.com/orocrm/orocrm-installationtechnical-issues-or-problems/topic/orocrm-3.1.6-admin-panel-401-error-on-apirestlatestnavigationitemspinbar/ and https://forum.oroinc.com/orocrm/orocrm-installationtechnical-issues-or-problems/topic/no-token-in-tokenstorage-error-after-update-to-3.1.13/ but it does not seem to have any effect.
Also tried adding `proxy_pass_header       Set-Cookie;` into Nginx proxy config for the site, but it had no effect either.
If the machine is accessed form the local network bypassing the proxy - the problem does not manifest itself and OroCRM functions correctly.
Thats how far I could google myself to. Any suggestions how to get this corretced would be welcome.

Andrius

Answer (score 1):

One needs to add

```
proxy_set_header X-CSRF-Header $cookie__csrf;
```

into the location part of Nginx config for the site.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have SSL enabled you should change Nginx option to: `fastcgi_param HTTPS on;`

Also you probably got 401 not 404

Here is the snippet that is simply worked for me. Tested on two sites behind cloudflare.

```
location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
    set $is_admin "off";
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /admin {
     set $is_admin "on";
     fastcgi_param HTTPS $is_admin;
     try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config|install|index)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;

    # on - is working for admin side
    # off - for the frontend
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $is_admin;
    fastcgi_param X-CSRF-Header $cookie__csrf;
```